# Azure mobile app return 401 (Unauthorized) even after successful login.

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm using custom authentication with facebook to let my users login to the app service. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error when calling "InvokeApiAsync"

"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Unauthorized)"

I'm using the following code that worked with the 1.x.x branch of the NuGet package, Its only after updating that I get this error message.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jToken = new Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject();
jToken.Add("access_token", token);

var user = await _mobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, jToken);

var result= await _mobileService.InvokeApiAsync<GetContactListRequest, GetContactListResponse>("GetContactList", new GetContactListRequest());
```

The LoginAsync part works and the user variable contains an user  with a token (_mobileService.CurrentUser does as well). It's when I call "InvokeApiAsync that i get the Unauthorized error.

The mobile service

```
[Authorize]
public class GetContactListController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/CustomRegistration
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(GetContactListRequest request)
    {
        try
        {
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new GetContactListResponse());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
        }
    }    
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Are you using custom authentication or are you using the built-in Facebook authentication? It looks like you're using the latter. Do you see any errors if you turn on application logging?

Comment: I'm using custom authentication, its where I get my facebook token from that I use in the (successful) LoginAsync call

Answer (score 2):

Try enabling application logging for your mobile app backend (you can do this in the portal). If the issue is in the platform authentication pipeline, then you will get more details about the auth failure there. Otherwise, it's more likely to be in your application code (either client or server).

If you have a Fiddler trace, that would also be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Comment: To log your client requests, either use Fiddler as Chris said, or you can add another delegating handler. See [https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!).

Comment: To turn on client logging, see [Help, my app isn't working!](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!) in the Mobile Apps wiki.